# Textures not displaying in Solid Shading mode

Tags: objects

OK, a question for who ever is the Blender expert. I am using Blender on a Linux (Debian) machine. I just updated to 2.73 and have a problem. I can't get any image in solid view. No matter what I do I get nothing. 2.73 works fine on my windows machine but not on the Linux system.

Comment: Solid *view*? Textures are displayed in Texture and Material *modes* only.

Comment: it probably has to do with OpenGL driver.

Answer (score 1):

This currently only works for Blender Render(Internal) since it's used for displaying textures that are being baked to and Cycles uses the Active Texture node to do this instead.

Up until last year, it was also used for Texture Painting, now Materials are used for this instead.

Whatever texture is assigned to the faces in the UV Image Editor is what will be displayed.

[image]